# The number "Average burndown" in DevOps. How is it calculated?

Tags: azure-devops, task, planning

I use the dashboard in Azure DevOps, and there is a pre-made widget there named Sprint Burndown. The number in the top middle of that chart says Average Burndown. How is that calculated?

I have three developers working for me in a project. Let's say:

Dev A estimates a task to 10 hours, and writes **6** in "completed" in a task at the end of the day.
Dev B estimates a task to 4 hours, but in reality it actually took 6, so he writes **6** in completed.
Dev C estimates a task to 7, but he managed to complete it in **6**, so he too writes 6 in completed.

The completed hours add up to 18. Is it only the numbers "completed hours" that are counted in a calculation of the "average burndown"? Does estimated and remaining enter into it at all?

Does anybody know the exact formula?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the inner workings of that exact widget, but I think the problem is that you're looking at *hours*. Burndowns are based on *story points*. I'd expect that the widget is looking at the completed story points per sprint.

Answer (score 1):

**Average burndown** is the average work completed per interval or iteration.

The **Average Burndown** assumes that every interval is the same length. It does not consider months that are different lengths. Additionally, it assumes that the interval between the Start Date and the first month is a full month, even if the length of time between Start Date and the first month's end date does not match your typical length of a month.

[image]

[image]

For more details, you can see:

- [Configure a Burndown or Burnup widget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/configure-burndown-burnup-widgets?view=azure-devops)
- [Configure and monitor sprint burndown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/configure-sprint-burndown?view=azure-devops&tabs=remaining-work%2Cmay)